# Client sent me distribution certificate and login username passwords to the development portal, but no private key

Tags: ios, testing, certificate, private-key

The distribution certificate is actually downloaded from Apple's development portal. Is there a way for me to generate the private key for the distribution certificate? Or the private key has to be generated by the computer that created the distribution certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to code-sign your app for distribution, you're going to need that private key.

Either you can create a ***new*** private/public key and distribution certificate (which your client will likely not be happy with, since that invalidates all his certificates), or you need to have him send you that private key so you can do your code-signing and building for distribution.